# RestKit - I want to map to NSManagedObjects but handle persistence myself

Tags: ios, json, core-data, persistence, restkit

I am using RestKit to interface with an API in an iOS app. I would like to use RKObjectManager and have mappings to my CoreData NSManagedObjects. However, the API responses (as JSON arrays) don't match up exactly with my CoreData model and the biggest problem is that not all objects returned by the API have primary keys (I have no control over the API).

Is there a way that I can use RestKit to map to the managed objects but handle persisting the objects to CoreData myself?